# Intrinsics in Visual Studio only working with MSVC, Clang and Intel Compiler say "unknown type name '__m512d'"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I am working on a project in Visual Studio with MSVC compiler and everything worked fine so far. For ...reasons... I wanted to use a different compiler. I tried Clang and the Intel Compiler but both show the exact same behavior: I get a lot of error/compiler messages like "unknown type name '__m512d'" or "use of undeclared identifier '_mm512_set1_pd'; did you mean '_mm_set1_epi64'?".

When I specify compiler flag "-march=native", I instead get error messages like "member reference base type '__m512d' (vector of 8 'double' values) is not a struct or union".

As soon as I switch back to MSVC compiler, everything works fine and the code compiles. I included `<immintrin.h>` and that should be everything, I need to do to use intrinsics or am I mistaken? Support for intrinsics is enabled in configuration settings.

Comment: For clang at least, there appears to be an [`avx512fintrin.h`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/avx512fintrin_8h.html) file